# Spring LDAP Spring Ldap Embedded doesn't set ldaptemplate base

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap, spring-ldap

To test ma LDAP service. I set up the embedded LDAP config like that:

```yaml
spring:
  ldap:
    base: OU=Internals,DC=int,DC=springboot,DC=dev
    username: uid=admin
    password: secret
    urls: ldap://localhost:8389/
    embedded:
      base-dn: DC=springboot,DC=dev
      credential:
        username: uid=admin
        password: secret
      ldif: classpath:export2-ldap.ldif
      port: 8389
      validation:
        enabled: false
```

I notice that the `ldaptemplate` base is not correctly set:
[image]

I've dug into the `EmbeddedLdapAutoConfiguration`  and `LdapAutoConfiguration` code, and I've noticed that the `EmbeddedLdapAutoConfiguration` creates a bean `LdapContextSource`, without the base, before the LdapAutoConfiguration class.

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
    @ConditionalOnClass(ContextSource.class)
    static class EmbeddedLdapContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        @DependsOn("directoryServer")
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean
        LdapContextSource ldapContextSource(Environment environment, LdapProperties properties,
                EmbeddedLdapProperties embeddedProperties) {
            LdapContextSource source = new LdapContextSource();
            if (embeddedProperties.getCredential().isAvailable()) {
                source.setUserDn(embeddedProperties.getCredential().getUsername());
                source.setPassword(embeddedProperties.getCredential().getPassword());
            }
            source.setUrls(properties.determineUrls(environment));
            return source;
        }

    }
```

Is it normal, is not possible to use both spring.ldap.base and spring.ldap.embedded.* ? Or maybe something is not correctly set in my projet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this with the following:

```java
@Bean
public LdapContextSource createLdapConfig(LdapProperties properties, Environment environment,
        ObjectProvider<DirContextAuthenticationStrategy> dirContextAuthenticationStrategy) {
    LdapAutoConfiguration config = new LdapAutoConfiguration();
    return config.ldapContextSource(properties, environment, dirContextAuthenticationStrategy);
}
```

As @Saikat noted, it appears both spring, and the unboundid embedded LDAP server are configured to create a `LdapContextSource` if it doesn't exist already... Sounds like the embedded LDAP server is winning the race, and screwing things up for everyone else.

The above code gets around the problem by just forcing the creation / configuration of a `LdapContextSource`, and thus not letting Spring nor the embedded ldap server try to create a `LdapContextSource`.